# Retirar auto-complete de nome de variável no Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, autocompletar, ide, configuração

Queria saber se é possível retirar auto-complete de sugestão de nome para variável no eclipse. Isso incomoda pois quando aperto a tecla espaço ele insere a sugestão ao invés de deixar o que digitei.

Veja como está abaixo:

[Auto-complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8znKE.gif)